# How to trigger submit on form the right way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I need to trigger a submit on a form but then handle it with javascript. This is how the component looks like

```
var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    alert("YES again");
    return;
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="postCon">
          <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <textarea className="textA input" placeholder="Your comment" ref="author" />
          </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
})
```

and this is the jquery that are supose to trigger the submit to the correct react method

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            $('.textA').autosize();
        });
        $('.textA').keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).closest("form").submit();
                return false; //prevent duplicate submission
            }
        });
    </script>
```

The problem is that the form will be sent and the handleSubmit is never triggered? Is this the right way of doing it or am I overcomplicating things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use keyboard events from React - http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html
For example:

```
var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    alert("YES again");
    return;
  },
  handleKeyPress: function(e){console.log(e.which);if(e.which == 13){this.handleSubmit();}},
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="postCon">
          <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <textarea onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} className="textA input" placeholder="Your comment" ref="author" />
          </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
})
```

Comment: Just to add to this, rather than posting a new answer: calling a form's `submit()` method directly doesn't trigger its `submit` event, which is why you should use the above technique.